# How do you get past Field E12?

Tags: gemcraft-labyrinth

This Field is stopping my progress, how do I get past it?

[image: Field E12]

Where should I be Placing the Towers/Traps and walls, and with what gems should I fill them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in this video, which probably does a better job of explaining the strategy than I could do in text:

The basic strategy seems to be to focus on the upper left corner, and build your defenses on either side of this corner for maximum effect.